# SSRS Pie Chart Showing Incorrect Data

Tags: charts, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, pie-chart, epicorerp

[image]

I have a Pie Chart that is showing incorrect data but I do not know how to correct it. It is showing Orders that have been shipped either Late or On Time. The problem is I have 1 order where part of it was shipped on time and the other part was late, therefore it is appearing in both groups as you can see in the image. I just want it to appear once like the first table in the image but I cannot do this in a Pie Chart as I need to group it by ActualOnTime field, but when it does that it duplicates it.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: I can't think of a way that you'll be able to do this in the chart. It might help if you give an example of your dataset but I doubt it. I assume there are two records for this order - an On Time and a Late. It'll probably be easier to do it in the dataset SQL rather than creating custom code.

Comment: Agree with Hannover, do this in the dataset query, or if you need the detail, do this in a separate dataset query that just supplies the data for the chart. You could even do the count in the query so only two records, in this case, are sent to the report.